# How to use function ends-with in selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, ends-with

I look up the information that lxml does not support xpath2.0 so that it can't use ends-with, so selenium can't use ends-with how to use it or replace ends-with. thank you very much indeed！！!

HTML sample

```
<span id="xxxxx_close">wwwww</span>
```

The `'xxxxx'` part of `@id` is random

Comment: Can you share HTML example and your desired output?

Comment: exampl  <span id="xxxxx_close">wwwww</span>，the 'xxxxx' is random.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply an ends-with CSS selector:

```
By.cssSelector("[id$=_close]")
```

There's no need of including span tag in css selector search as well.

Comment: In case there is a `<button id="yyyyy_close">Close</button>` on page you still think that there is no need to specify tag name? Also note that your code is not a Python

Comment: oh yes. my code is specific to Java.
And if <button id="yyyyy_close">Close</button> is present in that case you can always go for filtering elements based on the criteria that you need.

Answer (score 0):

The [`ends-with`](https://docs.mendix.com/refguide5/xpath-ends-with) [XPath Constraint Function](https://docs.mendix.com/refguide5/xpath-constraint-functions) is part of **XPath v2.0** but as per the current implementation *Selenium* supports **XPath v1.0**.

As per the *HTML* you have shared to identify the element you can use either of the [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `XPath` using [`contains()`](https://docs.mendix.com/refguide5/xpath-contains):

  - `xpath` using *contains* for `id` attribute:

    ```
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(@id,'_close')]")).click();
    ```
  - `xpath` using *contains* for `id` and `innerHTML` attribute:

    ```
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(@id,'_close') and contains(.,'wwwww')]")).click();
    ```
- Alternatively, you can also use *CssSelector* as follows:

  - `css_selector` using *ends-with (i.e. `$` wildcard)* clause for `id` attribute:

    ```
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span[id$='_close']").click();
    ```
  - `css_selector` using *contains (i.e. `*` wildcard)* clause for `id` attribute:

    ```
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span[id*='_close']").click();
    ```

Comment: That will work as long as there's no `_click` in the *middle* of any other element's id. While it's probably very unlikely, if it happens it can be a pretty nasty bug...

Comment: @jianyi Any feedback on my answer?